# Why is phpseclib producing incompatible certs?

Tags: php, c++, c, openssl, phpseclib

Why is it that when I try to use a certificate/key pair generated from phpseclib, the OpenSSL server code errors out? Certs/Keys generated from OpenSSL work fine. How do I fix this?

Certificate/Key Generation taken straight from [phpseclib documentation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/examples.html#selfsigned):

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

// create private key / x.509 cert for stunnel / website
$privKey = new Crypt_RSA();
extract($privKey->createKey());
$privKey->loadKey($privatekey);

$pubKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$pubKey->loadKey($publickey);
$pubKey->setPublicKey();

$subject = new File_X509();
$subject->setDNProp('id-at-organizationName', 'phpseclib demo cert');
//$subject->removeDNProp('id-at-organizationName');
$subject->setPublicKey($pubKey);

$issuer = new File_X509();
$issuer->setPrivateKey($privKey);
$issuer->setDN($subject->getDN());

$x509 = new File_X509();
//$x509->setStartDate('-1 month'); // default: now
//$x509->setEndDate('+1 year'); // default: +1 year

$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $subject);
echo "the stunnel.pem contents are as follows:\r\n\r\n";
echo $privKey->getPrivateKey();
echo "\r\n";
echo $x509->saveX509($result);
echo "\r\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Phpseclib requires you to call `$x509->setSerialNumber("0")` otherwise it will produce an invalid cert.

Comment: From what I understand of the X.509 specs it's a technically valid cert but a lot of implementations add additional constraints above and beyond what the X.509 specs say. Like if you do `openssl x509 -in phpseclib.cer -noout -text` it'll parse the cert even if the server won't accept it.

Comment: @neubert not in this case because phpseclib still has a serial number field, but it is of size 0 which is illegal in BER encoding